# Low pass filter in iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios, filter, filtering, signal-processing

I have code that implements a low-pass filter in order to detect a blow on the mic.
I can't understand how to determine the frequency and pick my own ALPHA:

```
lowPassResults = ALPHA * peakPowerForChannel + (1.0 - ALPHA) * lowPassResults;
```

This should detect a blow on the mic.

I want to get a new ALPHA to implement a lowpass filter with fc = 1 khz or higher.

How do i pick another ALPHA to do that ?

They took ALPHA=0.05 and according to Wikipedia formula, with sample rate of 30 times a second which they did, I got fc of 1.2 Hz.

Or should I take a sample rate of 44.1 kHz ? We sample the signal at 30 Hz.

Comment: i didnt know i have to accept answers! i just mention now.. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a simple recursive low pass filter which is just being used to smooth the measured (instantaneous) power from the microphone. Typically you want a low cut-off frequency, e.g. 1 Hz, so that you filter out all the noise and just get a smoothed power measurement. Increasing the cut off frequency (increasing ALPHA) will make the output respond faster but will introduce more noise. Conversely decreasing the cut off frequency (reducing ALPHA) will make the output respond more slowly but will also reduce the amount of noise.

Note that if you're only updating the filter at 30 Hz then you can't set the cut-off frequency to 1 kHz. The [Nyquist rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_rate) is 15 Hz so you can only filter at frequencies below this. Besides, it makes no sense to try and filter at such a high frequency if all you want to do is to detect blowing on the mic.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i dont want to detect a blow. the final goal is to detect a certain frequency by SUB between 2 lowpass filters, and get a band pass filter. it seems logic to you ??? how did they sample at 30hz only ?? they need to detect below 400hz ? here is the link:http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-detecting-when-a-user-blows-into-the-mic/

Comment: OK - well you should really re-consider your approach then - use an FFT to get a power spectrum and then inspect the bins for the range of frequencies of interest - there are lots of posts on SO already covering how to do this.

Comment: FFT is great but i couldnt find something simple as this. aurioTouch is not that simple. can you direct me to a post that i can take my code and implement with it an fft ??? thanks.

Comment: Look at KissFFT - it's about as simple as practical FFTs get. http://sourceforge.net/projects/kissfft/

Comment: @Rant: did you actually read the `README` file in the KissFFT distribution ? It starts off by showing you how to implement an FFT in two lines of code.

Comment: To test for a signal frequency there are alternatives to FFT. Look up the Goertzel algorithm. The Goertzel algorithm has several advantages over a FFT for single tone detection.

Comment: @Shannon: it sounds like he is looking for a *range* of frequencies though (he mentioned a bandpass filter at one point) - a Goertzel filter is only really useful for a single specific frequency (i.e. tone detection)

Comment: With iOS 4.x, you can use the built-in Accelerate framework for a faster FFT than kissFFT.  Do not expect iOS to be as easy to code for as platforms that have been around a lot longer and that suck a lot more power to run.

Comment: @Paul R: Ok, I misunderstood.

Comment: ok thanks a lot for your answers. i was trying to detect 1 single tone,but as you know its not realy a single one in reality,every filter has its width (3db break point etc).. i just couldnt do that, so now i am trying to detect the width of a signal from the audio input, and it seems to be harder! the recorder is not aqurate and has a delay of 900ms added to the signal width.. see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111070/audio-recorder-minimum-response-time

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-C-coding-for-a-low-pass-filter) gives perhaps a clearer version of the formula, with code for choosing alpha:

```
void lowPassFrequency(double* input, double* output, int points)
{
    double RC = 1.0/(CUTOFF*2*3.14); 
    double dt = 1.0/SAMPLE_RATE; 
    double alpha = dt/(RC+dt);
    output[0] = input[0]
    for(int i = 1; i < points; ++i)
    { 
        output[i] = output[i-1] + (alpha*(input[i] - output[i-1]));
    }
}
```

Note that it works on all sample points at once, rather than over time as in original question.